# Cost comparison optimization calculator code

Tags: python, cost-based-optimizer

I have a problem where I need to calculate the best price for a variable price.

Basically paper pageCost

```
1000 pack = .03 per sheet
500 pack = .04 per sheet
100 pack = .055 per sheet
Singles = .1
```

It needs to figure out the best combination for the best price.

I have been using python 3.5 if, elif and else along with the while statements and have a counter += 1 line implemented but that's as far as I can get.

Any thoughts?

Comment: so this is homework?